# cscript add network printer

Tags: printing, wsh

I trying to create a script that creates a Network printer.

But I get error "The inf file name must be fully qualified."

```
cscript  C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs -p "printername" -s "http://[servername]:631/ipp/r/1234" -a -m "HP Color LaserJet 2700 Series PCL6" -i C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prnhp002.inf_amd64_neutral_04d05d1f6a90ea24\prnhp002.inf
```

Comment: Perhaps surround the `-i` argument in double quotes, like you have done for `-p`, `-s` and `-m`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that script, but the error seems self-explanatory. It's complaining because it can't find the `inf` file or it believes you haven't specified a fully qualified path, this is likely due to the command line argument `-i` not being interpreted correctly.

Usually placing the `-i` argument value in double quotes should resolve this error *(which you seemed to do for every other argument but `-i`)*.

```
cscript  C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prndrvr.vbs -p "printername" -s "http://[servername]:631/ipp/r/1234" -a -m "HP Color LaserJet 2700 Series PCL6" -i "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prnhp002.inf_amd64_neutral_04d05d1f6a90ea24\prnhp002.inf"
```

Comment: @Hans I'm not sure then it was a bit of a stab in the dark, would need to see the source of `prndrvr.vbs` to debug further.

Comment: @Hans the fact it says "fully qualified" and it's a network printer, are you sure it's not expecting you to point to the `inf` file in the remote path so something like `-i "\\[servername]\c$\..."`? This is starting to look more like a technical issue rather than a programming one, you'd be best asking on [sf] or [su] rather than here.